# Pysparkling 2 reset monotonically_increasing_id from 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a spark dataframe into two pieces and defined the row number for each of the sub-dataframe. But I found that the function monotonically_increasing_id will still define the row number from the original dataframe.

Here is what I did in python:

```
# df is the original sparkframe
splits = df.randomSplit([7.0,3.0],400) 

# add column rowid for the two subframes
set1 = splits[0].withColumn("rowid", monotonically_increasing_id())
set2 = splits[1].withColumn("rowid", monotonically_increasing_id())

# check the results
set1.select("rowid").show()
set2.select("rowid").show()
```

I would expect the first five elements of rowid for the two frames are both 1 to 5 (or 0 to 4, can't remember clearly):

```
set1: 1 2 3 4 5
set2: 1 2 3 4 5
```

But what I actually got is:

```
set1: 1 3 4 7 9 
set2: 2 5 6 8 10
```

The two subframes' row id are actually their row id in the original sparkframe df not the new ones.

As a newbee of spark, I am seeking helps on why this happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what version of Spark are you using? The `monotonically_increasing_id` method implementation has been changed a few times. I can reproduce your problem in Spark 2.0, but it seems the behavior is different in spark 2.2. So it could be a bug that was fixed in newer spark release.

That being said, you should **NOT** expect the value generated by `monotonically_increasing_id` to be increase **consecutively**. In your code, I believe there is only one partition for the dataframe. According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, **but not consecutive**. **The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits**. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.
>
> As an example, consider a DataFrame with two partitions, each with 3
>   records. This expression would return the following IDs: 0, 1, 2,
>   8589934592 (1L << 33), 8589934593, 8589934594.

So if you code should not expect the rowid to be increased consecutively.

Besides, you should also consider caching scenario and failure scenarios. Even if monotonically_increase_id works as what you expect -- increase the value consecutively, it still will not work. What if your node fails? The partitions on the failed node will be regenerated from the source or last cache/checkpoint, which might have a different order thus different rowid. Eviction out of cache also causes issue. Assuming that after generating a dataframe and you cache it to memory. What if it is evicted out of memory. Future action will try to regenerate the dataframe again, thus gives out different rowid.

Comment: Thank you Lan. I am using spark 2.0. Do you have any suggestions on labeling rowid consecutively increasing?

Comment: I cannot think of a solution that works in ALL scenarios. Assuming that monotonically_increase_id works as what you expect -- increase consecutively, it still will not work for you. Why? What if your node fails? The partitions on the failed node will be regenerated from the source or last cache/checkpoint, which might have a different order thus different rowid. Failure scenarios are rare. Another scenario is more common though. Assuming that after generating a dataframe and you cache it to memory. What if it is evicted out of memory. Future action will try to regenerate the dataframe again.